# Javascript - Replace only if there is a perfect match

Tags: javascript, regex, join, replace

I am currently studying javascript and I stumbled upon this problem. Is there a way I can specify to replace the words only if there is a perfect match?

PS: I thought that 'g' will fix the problem but it only did it half-way.

```js
var text = "Isabella is moving to New York in March";
var words = ["is","in"];
var combine = new RegExp(words.join("|"),"g");

text = text.replace(combine,"REPLACE");
console.log(text);
```

Comment: _perfect match_ meaning...???

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir  perfect match is different from a partial match, as in; it would not match banana in "a pile of bananas" but would in "a banana pile"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the joined words in a group (preferably non-capturing) and then surround the groub with word boundaries `\b` so the regexp will look like this:

```
/\b(?:word1|word2|...|wordn)\b/g
```

**Change:**

```
var combine = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + words.join("|") + ")\\b", "g");
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^^
```

**Example:**

```js
var text = "Isabella is moving to New York in March";
var words = ["is","in"];
var combine = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + words.join("|") + ")\\b","g");

text = text.replace(combine," REPLACE ");
console.log(text);
```

**Note:** the `g` modifier mean global (mean replace not only the first but all matches)

Answer (score 2):

Only put spaces in words :)

```js
var text = "Isabella is moving to New York in March";
var words = [" is "," in "];
var combine = new RegExp(words.join("|"),"g");

text = text.replace(combine," REPLACE ");
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

By perfect match, I assume you mean match only the words themselves and not inside of words that may contain the characters for a word you are searching for. You are looking for the word boundary functionality of RegExp. Try this modified code. Note the `\b` added to the end and start. Basically, it acts as an anchor that says match this RegEx only in the instance of a whole word matching the pattern. I also put the words in a capturing group so the word boundary applies to all of them.

```js
var text = "Isabella is moving to New York in March";
var words = ["is","in"];
var combine = new RegExp("\\b(" + words.join("|") + ")\\b","g");

text = text.replace(combine,"REPLACE");
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

different approach: parse string into array and work with this array

```js
var text = "Isabella is moving to New York in March";
    
var words = ['in', 'is'];
    
var result = text.split(' ').filter(el => {return !words.includes(el)}).join(' ');

console.log(result);
```